# StatusBarIcon with Dropbox like behavior

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3, macos-sierra

I want to make a MenuBar only app that checks and API every 30 seconds and changes the StatusBarIcon depending on the state of a flag. I've been following this tutorial: https://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/creating-a-os-x-menubar-only-app/ but I've only been able to do it the first time in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` function.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: NSSquareStatusItemLength)
    statusBarItem?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "locked")


    self.fetchOccupied { (occupied) in
        if (occupied) {
            self.statusBarItem?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "locked")
        } else {
            self.statusBarItem?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "unlocked")
        }
    }
}
```

After that, like I said, I want to check again every 30 seconds without having to click on the StatusBarItem but I can't put the loop inside that function because then the app will never start.

I don't know where to put the loop because I don't have a main ViewController or anything. I only have the AppDelegate class and the XIB file.

Where can I create the function to put the loop on? Maybe I can put that loop asynchronous in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` function?

Thank you.

Comment: Why **not** use a view controller? You don't need to put anything into the view.

Comment: @dfd Why does he or she have to use a view controller?

Comment: My bad. I was thinking about iOS apps, totally overlooking the "MenuBar" and the"OS X" in the link, focusing on StatusBarItem instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just run a clock to get a notification every 30 seconds.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateClock), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateClock() {
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.second],from:date as Date) as NSDateComponents
    if components.second == 0 || components.second == 30 {
        makeStatusMenu()
    }
}

func makeStatusMenu() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer: DispatchSourceTimer?

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

    self.timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: DispatchSource.TimerFlags(), queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated))
    self.timer?.scheduleRepeating(deadline: DispatchTime.now(), interval: DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(30), leeway: DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(0))
    self.timer?.setEventHandler(handler: {
        //loop body here
        print("timer fire", separator: "", terminator: "\n")
    })
    self.timer?.resume()
}
```